# I want to add registeration to my web by django. I did all things right:

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, user-controls

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tutorial
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def register (request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages():
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
            
    return render(request,
                 'main/register.html',
                 context={'form':form})
```

but still I get this error " 'dict' object is not callable
Request Method: POST Request
URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/ Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:     'dict' object is not callable "

Comment: remove parenthesis on this line `for msg in form.error_messages():`

Comment: Also it should be `for msg in form.errors: print msg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for msg in form.error_messages():
    print(form.error_messages[msg])
```

First, no where in the Django documentation is using `form.error_messages` for the error messages, and if `form.error_messages` is a dict, then there is a python problem -> `dict is not callable`, get the list of keys by calling `.keys()` on your dict.

According to Newest [Django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) to get errors from your forms is using `form.errors`.

```
for field, msg in form.errors.items():
    print(f'Field {key}: {msg}')
```